# Early Detection of peaks with Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, prediction

I am using Neural Network technique(Backward Learning). As a output for example I am giving the 18 point ahead value and as input I gave the  latest 5 point to train.(I tried the many combinations of input data 5,10, 20 ,30...).

For example, the way I trained my data:

t,    t+1,  t+2, t+3, t+4...    =>  t+22(4+18)

t+1, t+2, t+3, t+4, t+5...    =>  t+23

Exponential inputs:

t,    t+1,  t+2, t+4, t+8...    =>  t+26(8+18)

t+1, t+2, t+3, t+8, t+9...    =>  t+27

After I trained, I have done forward learning with the my trained values. I have observed that neural network won't able to catch the sudden peaks. Most of the time if I am going to predict 18 seconds ahead, it predicts the correct result 17 seconds later.

> Do you have any advice for me about how could I able to predict sudden peaks(that will happen t seconds later) with neural network?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I work with backpropagation and I observe the same behaviour. If I understood correctly, you don't have a true forecasting. Peeks, when present on data, are available to be "predicted" only after appear in the series, and you observe and apparent prediction with a delay.

I thinf you have to user a recurrent network.

Comment: I have also implemented RNN, but I wasn't able to get accurate results for N point ahead predictions.